# Django print invalid value from is_valid

Tags: django

I have a Django view that will save the value from a Post request

```
form=MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.added_on = timezone.now()
    post.save()
return redirect(index)
```

How do I print the invalid value which makes the is_valid() test to fail?

Comment: It is in `form.errors`. This is a dictionary-like object that maps the field names to a list of errors.

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use the [**`.errors`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) that a form has. It is a dictionary-like object that maps the name of fieds to a *list* of errors. For some fields the value might have *multiple* errors (for example a password can be too short, and not contain digits).

As specified in the documentation:

> Returns a dict that maps fields to their original ValidationError
> instances.
>
> ```
> >>> f.errors.as_data()
> {'sender': [ValidationError(['Enter a valid email address.'])],
> 'subject': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]}
> ```

The object also has some extra methods like [**`.errors.as_json`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json) that will convert the errors to a JSON blob.